# Making a paginated table showing as much rows as possible

Tags: tabulator

I want to display a paginated table that is showing five rows per page.
If there is not enough space to display five rows at a time I want it to only display four rows per page.
However all I can find is that you get to scroll through the table if there is any overflow and I can't find a way to disable the "scrollability" as I don't want the scrollbar to appear.
Is there a way to achieve what I have on my mind?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest in that case not setting a `paginationSize` on your table, but instead setting a `maxHeight` on your table that would fit 5 rows and a `minHeight` that will fit four rows. Tabulator will then automatically adjust the page size to fit the number of rows that will fill the table:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    minHeight:"200px",
    maxHeight:"225px",
});
```

you would need to tweak the max an min values in the example above to fit with the row height of your rows